# Android tinyalsa: cannot open device '/dev/snd/pcmC1D0c': Permission denied

Tags: android, permissions, alsa

I've built an Android app that uses tinyalsa through jni. When I call `pcm_open`, I get:

```
cannot open device '/dev/snd/pcmC1D0c': Permission denied
```

Unlike [this poster's case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405852/android-pcm-open-failed-cannot-open-device-dev-snd-pcmc0d1p), I do see the file in question if I `su -c 'ls /dev/snd'`. In fact, if I `stat` this file and the directories above it, all the way up to the root directory, the permissions that `stat` outputs conform to the permissions that I see on my ordinary linux workstation:

All of the directories are `0755/drwxr-xr-x`, and the file itself is `0660/crw-rw----`.

*Why would Android deny me permission, and what do I need to do about it?*

Despite this `755` permission on the directories above my device file, if I `adb shell` and then `ls /dev/snd`, I get `Permission denied`!

Edit: it has been suggested that the resolution to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410190/android-dir-permissions-are-r-x-but-i-still-get-permission-denied) (which, incidentally, is still unresolved) will solve my alsa issue; I don't know if it will or not. My concern is that the [source](https://github.com/tinyalsa/tinyalsa/blob/master/src/pcm.c) for `pcm_open` calls `open` on `/dev/snd/pcmC1D1c`, and that file does not have any permissions set for `a` (not `o` or `g`) users. Does the use of alsa require that I do something *more* than link libtinyalsa.so.1 when building my Android app?

Am I mistaken in my linking strategy? In my app's JNI modules, I included `pcm.c` and `pcm.h` from the primary [tinyalsa repository](https://github.com/tinyalsa/tinyalsa) and then followed standard procedure for opening an audio device with it.

Comment: why asking the same question again?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410190/android-dir-permissions-are-r-x-but-i-still-get-permission-denied

Comment: To me the questions are related, but they are different, and the answer to one question might not answer the other question. Even if I find an answer to the permissions issue on the directories above the device file, it is possible that alsa still be denied permission to access the device file.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs : clearer explanation is given in the edit above.